# How to express a list of lists of rules as functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Given a list of lists of rules as follows:

```
links = {{"scst" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", 
    "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", 
    "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "stel"}, {"scst" \[DirectedEdge] 
     "sfin"}, {"scst" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", 
    "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", 
    "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus"}, {"scst" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
    "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl"}, {"scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", 
    "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6"}};
```

Directed edges in each list go into the same vertex, such as in the first list, the edges go into "stel". I want to convert that list into a function of the form:

```
stel = f[scst, sfin, sbus] or
sfin = f[scst], etc.
```

Similar mapping should be implemented to the entire list `links`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[sfin, stel, sbus, ma6]

Table[{Evaluate @ ToExpression[links[[i, 1, 2]]] = 
    f @@ links[[i]][[All, 1]]}, {i, Length @ links}];
```

Now you can do:

```
stel
```

f["scst", "sfin", "sbus"]

```
{stel, sfin, sbus, ma6} // TableForm
```

[image]

The arguments of `f` are strings. If you convert them to expressions you get of course:

```
ToExpression /@ stel
```

f[scst, f["scst"], f["scst", "sfin", "swhl"]]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe.

```
(flist[#[[1, 2]]] = f[#[[All, 1]] /. List -> Sequence]) & /@ links
 
 (* {f["scst", "sfin", "sbus"], f["scst"], f["scst", "sfin", "swhl"], f["scst", "sfin"], f["scst", "sbus", "swhl"]} *)

flist["stel"]
 (* f["scst", "sfin", "sbus"] *)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
ClearAll[f, stel, sfin , sbus, swhl, ma6];
KeyValueMap[(Evaluate@Symbol[#] = #2) &, 
  GroupBy[Flatten@links, Last -> First, f @@ # &]];

(*Testing*)
{stel, sfin , sbus, swhl, ma6}
```

> {f["scst", "sfin", "sbus"], f["scst"], f["scst", "sfin", "swhl"],
> f["scst", "sfin"], f["scst", "sbus", "swhl"]}